# Django poor request response performance when using threads

Tags: python, django, multithreading, time, response

I'm trying to optimize the response time on a specific endpoint so I try using vanilla threads to make things on parallel. The problem is that the performance does not seems to improve and actually removing the threads from the view is giving me half of the time, when it should be running in parallel.

Here is some example:

```
def myView():
    do_a()
    return Response("ok")

def myView():
    do_a()
    thread = Thread(target=do_b)
    thread.start()
    return Response("ok")
```

myView without the thread is taking 30ms when the view with the thread that should be running do_b in paralle is actually taking 60ms.

I'm using django, django-restframework and mongodb when using the do_b thread (with djongo interface)

What's my problem here?

Comment: It's probably the PIL.  If all the code in `do_b` is Python code (that is, not waiting for I/O or calling into C), then there's no gain.  Python only allows one thread at a time to be executing Python code.  Your function can't return until `do_b` waits for something.

Comment: ok, I partially understand what you mean, but the my question is: What's is the point in using the default threading library in Python? And what can I do to accomplish a truly parallel executing code within django? (or some alternatives).

Comment: It isn't common to start long-running procedures in response to web requests.  Theoretically, if you did a `time.sleep(0.5)` in your thread, that would give the Django framework time enough to finish the request, and then your thread could move on.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the do_b() function is waiting for do_a() function to complete. So there is no performace gain. This is because do_a() function is not a thread. If you call do_b() function before do_a() function there can be a difference. If you think do_b() need to run without waiting for do_a you can add both in thread.

This is your current scenario:

```
import logging
import threading
import time


def do_a():
    logging.info("Function do_a starting")
    time.sleep(2)
    logging.info("Function do_a finishing")
    
    
def do_b():
    logging.info("Function do_b starting")
    time.sleep(2)
    logging.info("Function do_b finishing")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    format = "%(asctime)s: %(message)s"
    logging.basicConfig(format=format, level=logging.INFO,
                        datefmt="%H:%M:%S")
                        
    logging.info("Main    : before calling do_a")
    do_a()
    logging.info("Main    : after calling do_a")

    logging.info("Main    : before creating thread 2")
    x = threading.Thread(target=do_b)
    logging.info("Main    : before running thread 2")
    x.start()
    logging.info("Main    : wait for the thread to finish")
    x.join()
    logging.info("Main    : all done")
```

The output will be for 4 seconds:

```
03:23:11: Main    : before calling do_a
03:23:11: Function do_a starting
03:23:13: Function do_a finishing
03:23:13: Main    : after calling do_a
03:23:13: Main    : before creating thread 2
03:23:13: Main    : before running thread 2
03:23:13: Function do_b starting
03:23:13: Main    : wait for the thread to finish
03:23:15: Function do_b finishing
03:23:15: Main    : all done
```

But if do_a also added in thread

```
import logging
import threading
import time


def do_a():
    logging.info("Function do_a starting")
    time.sleep(2)
    logging.info("Function do_a finishing")
    
    
def do_b():
    logging.info("Function do_b starting")
    time.sleep(2)
    logging.info("Function do_b finishing")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    format = "%(asctime)s: %(message)s"
    logging.basicConfig(format=format, level=logging.INFO,
                        datefmt="%H:%M:%S")
                        
    logging.info("Main    : before creating thread 1")
    x = threading.Thread(target=do_a)
    logging.info("Main    : before running thread 1")

    logging.info("Main    : before creating thread 2")
    x = threading.Thread(target=do_b)
    logging.info("Main    : before running thread 2")
    x.start()
    logging.info("Main    : wait for the thread to finish")
    x.join()
    logging.info("Main    : all done")
```

The output can be in 2 seconds:

```
03:25:43: Main    : before creating thread 1
03:25:43: Main    : before running thread 1
03:25:43: Main    : before creating thread 2
03:25:43: Main    : before running thread 2
03:25:43: Function do_b starting
03:25:43: Main    : wait for the thread to finish
03:25:45: Function do_b finishing
03:25:45: Main    : all done
```